# How to check whether a Git commit exists on some remote?

Tags: git, version-control

I want to check whether a particular Git commit sha1 exists on a specific remote. I tried the following command:

```
git fetch <remote> <revision> -q --dry-run
```

The problem is that the command returns success not only when the revision is present on the remote, but also when it is present locally.

Is there some way to check this ignoring the local revision?

Comment: Adding `--depth=1` seems to work, not sure how/why.

Comment: @Sedfer Yes, it seems to work. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Just noting that @Sedfer's solution only works if the server allows it (as mentioned in my answer). For example github does allow it, but that may not be true for other servers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have fetched all remote heads, you can try

```
$ git branch -r --contains <commit-sha>
```

This will give you a list of branches which contain the commit and you can see if the result includes remote ones.

If you want this to work without having fetched the remote, then a server-side config must be present: `uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant=true` and the git versions of both server and client must be >= 2.5

Comment: Note that the latest protocols have an implied "allowReachableSHA1InWant" as the partial clone feature requires this. Of course Git is also moving away from SHA1, so the very name of the configuration item has become wrong too. :-)

Comment: One issue is this requires that all branch information be available locally, so this would require e.g. CI setups to do a full clone rather than a shallow clone to work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `--depth=1` seems to work.

I can not explain why it works, and I could not find any mention of this in the documentation. Probably wouldn't rely on this if I needed a robust solution.